# SSRS PIVOT TABLE QUERY to return days absent by month

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, toad

I have an SQL query with

```
startdate  23/09/2013
enddate    06/10/2013
days_absent 14
```

and I need to show the days _absent in a pivot table as Sep 7 and Oct 7 
instead of Sep 14

```
Month   Days_Absent
------------------------
   SEP        7
   OCT        7
```

Here is the query to populate the report:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ACCINJ_VIEW.STARTDATEOFABSENCE,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "Start Date of Absence" , 
TO_CHAR(ACCINJ_VIEW.ENDDATEOFABSENCE,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "End Date of Absence" , ACCINJ_VIEW.DAYSABSENT AS "Days Absent" , 
FROM ACCINJ_VIEW ACCINJ_VIEW, 
WHERE ACCINJ_VIEW.IDPERSONUNIQUEKEY = INJG_VIEW.IPERSONUNIQUEKEY(+) AND ov_VIEW.ACCDATE BETWEEN :ACCDATESTART AND :ACCDATEEND
```

I think this might work

```
 WITH all_days AS
 (
  SELECT first_day + LEVEL - 1 AS a_day
  FROM (
           SELECT  TO_DATE ( '05/08/2011' , 'DD/MM/YYYY')  AS first_day, -- Start Date 
                   TO_DATE ( '16/10/2011' , 'DD/MM/YYYY')  AS last_day   -- End Date
           FROM  dual
        )
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= last_day + 1 - first_day
 )
 SELECT   TO_CHAR (TRUNC(a_day,'MONTH'),'FMMonth YYYY')  AS month,
         COUNT (*)  AS day
 FROM   all_days
 GROUP BY  TRUNC (a_day, 'MONTH')
 ORDER BY  TRUNC (a_day, 'MONTH')
 /
```

**Result:**

```
 MONTH                 DAY
-------------- ----------
August 2011            27
September 2011         30
October 2011           16
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to show your query please :)

Comment: Facing an issue when using the above code in my main script. However, the code works fine independently.

Comment: @user2856113 you just have the days absent between the dates or every date which contains a absence ?

Comment: In my pivot I just what to show the total number of days  absence by month  eg for every date which contains a absences